# session variable disappears after importing php webpage

Tags: php, session, session-variables

I have a `cart.php` webpage, which, on open, has a `SESSION` variable `$_SESSION['userid']`. After calling  `echo include 'header.php';`, that variable is unset.

header.php:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <link href="../stylesheets/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
//            session_start();
        ?>
        <div class="headerClass">
            <div >
                <img src="images/logo.jpg" id="logoId"/>
            </div>
            <div class="nameClass">
                ShopAholics
            </div>

            <div class="myCart" onclick="window.open('cart.php')">
                <button type="button">My Cart</button>
            </div>
            <div class="myAccount">
                <button type="button" onclick="window.open('accountActivities.php')">My Account</button>
            </div>
            <div class="logout">
                <button type="button" onclick="<?php if(isset($_SESSION))unset($_SESSION['userid']);?>">Logout</button>
            </div>
        </div>       
    </body>
</html>
```

If i try to add the commented line, evey time that is called a new session is issued. Why is that?

UPDATE: i tried adding `session_star`t in the beginning of `header.php`, now every time it starts a new session; also, i already have a `session_start` in the `cart.php`, which works just fine.

Comment: call @session_start(); always, before nothing else ...

Comment: you're wondering why when including `header.php`, `$_SESSION['user_id']` is being unset? here: `<button type="button" onclick="<?php if(isset($_SESSION))unset($_SESSION['userid']);?>">Logout</button>`

Comment: that onclick should take place only if the Logout button is pressed, isn't it?

Comment: you seem to be confused on server vs client side scripting. server side comes first. you're unsetting that session variable before it even makes your click event. either just submit if you have a form, then unset there, or use an XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: thank you very much @Ghost, you were right, commenting it did make it work, Thank you very much!!!...but, it is weird, it does not unset my variables in other webpages i am calling it from!

Comment: @SummerCode either use jquery ajax or just plain xmlhttprequest vanilla js, create a PHP which handles that unsetting of that session variable and call that.